# Android: вывод данных через другой класс

Tags: webview, android, java, классы

Есть 2 класса: Main и Banner.
Задача выводить окно браузера из Banner в Main.
делаю так:
в Main:

```
Banner banner = new Banner();
banner.view();
```

в Banner:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Banner extends Main{
    WebView mWebView;
    public void view() {
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.link_banner_url));
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку типа "...Unable to start activity Componentinfo...".
Добавлю что классы находятся в разных пакетах.
В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: зачем банер расширять мейном??

Comment: Для примера написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все неправильно. `Main` должен наследоваться от `Activity`. Если хочется так сильно вынести инициализацию баннера в отдельный класс (что есть плохая практика), не надо его наследовать от `main` и надо просто передать ему в конструктор ссылку на `main` и искать `view` на этой `activity`.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Banner {
    WebView mWebView;
    public void view(Activity v) {
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.banner);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.link_banner_url));
    }
}

.............................

вызывать banner.view(this)
```

;

Comment: Баннер выношу в отдельный класс - потому что он много где используется, не хочется в каждом активити писать его инициализацию.

Comment: работает, если убрать "mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);", ищу проблему